# How to run an Azure SQL Server Stored Procedure using an Automation Account Runbook with Managed Identity?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to run SQL Server DB index and statistics maintenance activating a stored procedure called `AzureSQLMaintenance` with a PowerShell Runbook in Automation Account.

Since I don't want to use standard SQL Server authentication, I am trying to use Managed Identities.

Online I found some Microsoft documentation getting quite close to the point on Microsoft Tech Community [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/443021/need-to-configure-the-maintenance-plan-for-themult.html) and [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/automating-azure-sql-db-index-and-statistics-maintenance-using/ba-p/368974), but both the threads are missing some pieces. A very good clue clue was given to me by [this blog post](https://global.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/azure-sql-databases-stored-procedure/) but it was missing Managed Identity Authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed, after a couple of days of tests, to make it work, so I'll write the whole process down in case anybody will need to do the same:

1. Under **Account Settings > Identity** System Assigned Managed Identity must be set to **On**, and we'll need the `Object (principal) Id`, so remember to mark it down
2. In my Azure SQL Database Server, under **Settings > Azure Active Directory**, we'll need to check the value of the `Azure Active Directory admin`. In my case, this is a group
3. In **Azure Active Directory**, edit the group individuated on the previous step and add the `Object (principal) Id` obtained at the step 1 as a member of the group
4. A **Powershell Runbook** in Automation Account needs to be created
5. The powershell Runbook Code will need to look something like

```
Write-Output "Run started"

# Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

# Connect to the the account used the Managed Identity
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

# Get a Token
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net ).Token

# Initialize the connection String
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=db-server-name.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=<db-name>;Connect Timeout=60" 

# Set the Token to be used by the connection
$sqlConnection.AccessToken = $token

# Open the connection
$sqlConnection.Open()

Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened"

# Define the SQL command to run
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

# Allow Long Executions
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

# Associate the created connection
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection

Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure"

# Execute the SQL command
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'exec [dbo].[AzureSQLMaintenance] @parameter1 = ''param1Value'', @parameter2 = ''param2Value'' '
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed"

# Close the SQL connection
$sqlConnection.Close()

Write-Output "Run completed"
```

At this point, run a test on the Runbook: in my case it worked perfectly, even if it took a while (that's the reason for the parameter `$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0`)